# proficient JSON structure for comment section between Patient and Doctor?

Tags: javascript, json, relation

I'm currently developing a medical app with authentication functionality between patients and doctors.

Now the current JSON structure for patients & doctor is as follows:

## Patients

```js
"Patients": {
  "w14FKo72BieZwbxwUouTpN7UQm02": {
    "name": "Naseebullah Ahmadi",
    "profession": "Student",
    "gender": "Male",
    "type": "Patient",
    "doctors": ["Ernest"],
    "age": "20",
    "DOB": "02/06/1997",
    "address": "122 Atherstone Court",
    "contactNumber": "07473693312",
    "profilePicture": "../Images/profile.jpg",
    "history": {
      "age": "22",
      "weight": "53",
      "height": "172",
      "bmi": "20.4",
      "thermometer": "36.7",
      "calories": "537",
      "bpm": "87",
      "fat": "11",
      "allergies": ["Peanuts", "Penicilin"]
    },
    "appointments": [{
      "date": "25th Jul",
      "time": "13:00",
      "type": "Doctor",
      "name": "Ernest Kamavuako"
    }],
    "ecg": [""],
    "heartSound": [""]
  },
```

Where each Patient is identified by their Id "example: `w14FKo72BieZwbxwUouTpN7UQm02`"

## Doctor

```js
"Doctors": {
  "VoxHFgUEIwRFWg7JTKNXSSoFoMV2": {
    "name": "Ernest Kamavuako",
    "gender": "Male",
    "type": "Doctor",
    "Patients": ["Naseebullah"],
    "age": "30",
    "dob": "20/12/1970",
    "address": "122 Harrow Street",
    "contactNumber": "07473033312",
    "profilePicture": "../Images/profile.jpg"
  }
}
```

Now the problem is: Each doctor is able to read comments that the patient has left to them, and likewise each patient is able to read comments that each doctor left.

Both principles are able to have a max limit of 50 comments.

Currently, I'm not sure how to represent the "comment" object and how it should be laid out.

This question is purely for the benefit of understanding the relation between actors that are being played.

Comment: Is there some reason why comments cannot simply be an array? Any special considerations?

Comment: No not really. I presume it could an object of arrays, where each key might represent the patient, its value might be an array of messages?

But its an open choice, whatever suggestion would suffice @Thebluefish

Answer (score 0):

You can have a json object for comments like this

```
"Comments": {
  "<doctorsId>:<patientsId>": {
    "doctorsComments" : '["comment1", "comment2"]',
    "patientsComments": '["comment1", "comment2"]'
  }
}
```

Here You can directly access the comment object if you have the doctors and patients ids.

Comment: I see. This is very interesting because it reduces nested objects here